# How can I change the pointer in shared_ptr without losing the ability to delete the memory?

Tags: c++, memory, boost, shared-ptr

I faced a problem with `std::shared_ptr`. I have a code:

```
void Receive(const std::shared_ptr<char[]>& data, uint32_t length) {
  this->next->Receive(data + 2, length - 2);
}
```

I need to increment shared_ptr by 2 without losing the ability to delete the memory.

I don't want to copy data, because the data is already in memory and I own the data. It would be foolish to copy the data just to displace and delete the old data if I can just change the pointer without losing performance. Can shared_ptr contain and return one pointer, but delete another?

As far as I know, the internals of shared_ptr contains a pointer to data which is returned by the `get()` function and contains a reference to a control block that counts references and is supposed to delete the memory when all references have gone.

So, since it contains pointer separately from control block, maybe I can somehow change it without changing the pointer to the allocated memory block in the control block, without losing the ability to delete the memory? If I can't, maybe I can do it with `boost::shared_ptr`?

I haven't checked it yet. I don't use the [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) library, but if it helps me I will.

Comment: Could you perhaps use `void Receive(char* data, uint32_t length)` instead? Or even consider `void Receive(std::span<char> data);`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that's what the aliasing contructor of `std::shared_ptr` is for. It keeps the same control block, but it allows you to use another pointer.

The signature is

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

In your case that would be

```
void Receive(const std::shared_ptr<char[]>& data, uint32_t length) {
  std::shared_ptr<char[]> alias(data, data.get()+2);
  this->next->Receive(alias, length - 2);
}
```

But I do question the use of `shared_ptr` in this case. Do you really have shared ownership in this case? Can you not figure out one part of code that could own this memory?

Comment: I'd be tempted to bubdle offset, length and shared ptr to buffer into a struct myself.  Implement + and ++ and length remaining and the like.  Also unary star and arriw dereference.  Overhead is modest, and debugging far more friendly.  Plus ptr and length are one bundle, not two arguments,

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont for another use-case maybe. But the function as specified would work better with just taking a `char*` and letting the call-site do the `sptr.get()` call. Because it's passing a `const std::shared_ptr<T>&`, so taking it by reference and not even taking part in ownership. In this case (as presented) using shared_ptr did nothing good

Comment: I mean, in theory, the call to `next->Recieve` could thread off the reading and take ownership from the passed in shared ptr, and return immediately, for example.