# A shared pointer to a section of memory belonging to another shared pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I know shared pointers are implied to share the same memory. But what if my shared pointer points to an element which is not the first in the memory of another shared pointer?

Consider a raw pointer example:

```
int* array = new int[10];
int* segment = &array[5];
```

Can I make the same thing with `array` and `segment` being shared pointers? Will they count references in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the pointer in shared\_ptr without losing the ability to delete the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68364460/how-can-i-change-the-pointer-in-shared-ptr-without-losing-the-ability-to-delete)

Comment: Yeah look up `aliasing constructor` for shared_ptr

Comment: @MikeVine can I have aliasing with `make_shared`? I only managed to find aliasing with a constructor

Comment: @Kaiyakha `make_shared()` cannot create an aliased `shared_ptr`, you must call the aliasing constructor directly. But you can make such a `shared_ptr` that aliases a `shared_ptr` that was created with `make_shared()`.

Comment: @JaMiT yes, but actually no as the headline of the post you suggested is not explicit enough

Comment: @Kaiyakha The headline is not what answers your question. Many people are downright awful at writing titles for their questions. Please read the question body to see if it asks what you are asking (or is close enough), and the answer to see if it answers your question. (It might not, but please give it a fair shot.)

Comment: @JaMiT You didn't quite get my point. Awful headlines is one of the major reasons for duplicates. How am I supposed to find an already existing question if its title does not reflect its content? How other people would find it?

Comment: @Kaiyakha *"How am I supposed to find an already existing question if [...]"* -- you're not necessarily supposed to.  Flagging as a duplicate is not saying "you should have found this"; it's saying "let's get all the answers in one place". That way someone searching and finding any of the duplicates can be directed to the same set of answers.

Comment: @JaMiT Reasonable, but posting duplicates may entail lots of downvotes and I will eventually get banned for asking new questions, so...

Comment: @Kaiyakha *"posting duplicates may entail lots of downvotes"* -- why would it? Being a duplicate should be a non-factor in up/down voting. Well-asked duplicates do not warrant down votes, and badly-asked duplicates do warrant down votes. Even if they are not closed as duplicates. *Example of a question closed as duplicate (not of this question) with plenty of up votes:  [What will happen when I call a member function on a NULL object pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533476/what-will-happen-when-i-call-a-member-function-on-a-null-object-pointer).* I believe your fear is misplaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` has an [*aliasing constructor*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) for exactly this kind of situation:

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* ptr ) noexcept;
```

> The *aliasing constructor*: constructs a `shared_ptr` which shares ownership information with the initial value of `r`, but holds an unrelated and unmanaged pointer `ptr`. If this `shared_ptr` is the last of the group to go out of scope, it will call the stored `deleter` for the object originally managed by `r`. However, calling `get()` on this `shared_ptr` will always return a copy of `ptr`. It is the responsibility of the programmer to make sure that this `ptr` remains valid as long as this `shared_ptr` exists, such as in the typical use cases where `ptr` is a member of the object managed by `r` or is an alias (e.g., downcast) of `r.get()`

For example:

```
auto array = std::make_shared<int[]>(10);
auto segment = std::shared_ptr<int>(array, &array[5]);
```